# create a string of replicated values with different replication frequency in r

Tags: r

I need to create a string of replicated values, which number of replicates depend on meeting certain conditions.
For example (this is a simplification; the actual task and conditions are more complicated):

Replicate three times values within the range 1:5, except for those that are integers of 4 that will be replicated four times .

The output should look as follows: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5

I created a loop to examine each value within the range:

This is where I got:

```
year<-(1:5)
r2<-NULL
for (x in 1:length(year))
  if(is.integer(4)){
    r<-rep(year[x],4)
    }else{
    r<-rep(year[x],3)
  }
 r2<-c(r2,r)
```

But is giving me:
[1] 5 5 5

It looks it's overwriting the outut.

I have also tried pre-defining tasks as follows:

```
year<-(1:5)
r<-rep(year[x],4)
r2<-rep(year[x],3)
for (x in 1:length(year))
  ifelse(is.integer(4),r,r2)
r3<-c(r2,r)
```

Which is giving me:
[1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5

But it does not recognize the condition and seems to be accepting both options for the same value, and overwriting the output.

I am sure this is very straight forward, but I'm new to programming and still struggling with it. I would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Thanks!!

UPDATE (Corrected following suggestions on the comments):

```
year<-(1:5)
r2<-NULL
for (x in 1:length(year)){
  if(year[x]%%4==0){
    r<-rep(year[x],4)
  }else{
    r<-rep(year[x],3)
   }
  r2<-c(r2,r)
}
```

It works!! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! I can't because this are not the actual values. I am trying to generate a code that will give me 365 entries per year, except for those that meet the conditions of leap years that will have 366 entries. Time periods may cover as many as 2500-4000 years, so the range may go for 1:2050 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the accolades after `for () {}`.
And in addition, you might want to check the modulus instead of `is.integer` which will check the variable type not the value.

```
year<-(1:5)
r2<-NULL
for (x in 1:length(year)){
  if(year[x] %% 4==0){
    r<-rep(year[x],4)
  }else{
    r<-rep(year[x],3)
  }
r2<-c(r2,r)
}

r2
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5
```

Comment: You beat me by seconds, @Bea! I tested the code as written in the OP, and the missing {} on the for loop are the problem.

Comment: I added the missing {} and used modules for setting conditions as suggested and it worked! Thanks!!!. Updated code on the main question :D